# SVG - Polyline with quadratic bezier

Tags: css, svg

I want to create a SVG path with several points and several bezier curves. If I add a bezier curve the SVG is not rendered. How can I have several bezier curves?

SVG

```
<polyline points="0,50 Q0,20 101,40  404,50" 
  stroke="black"
  stroke-width="3" fill="none"> 
</polyline >
```

Comment: Did you notice your element starts with polyline and ends with path ?

Comment: thx, I corrected it, but it still does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw a beziere curve you need to use the `<path>` element. So your example would become:

```
<path d="M0,50 Q0,20 101,40"  
  stroke="black"
  stroke-width="3" fill="none"> 
</path>
```

Now, if you wanted to add more connected curves you would write:

```
<path d="M0,50 Q0,20 101,40 Q100,0 120,40"  
  stroke="black"
  stroke-width="3" fill="none"> 
</path>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
<svg height="180" width="500">
    <polyline points="0,50 0,20 101,40 404,50" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Comment: If you need cubic or quadratic curves, check also this useful blog: http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/svg-curves/cubic-curve.html